# What's the difference between svn:eol and svn:eol-style

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a large subversion repository with files that are missing the eol-style and keywords properties.  I want to blanket set them but I noticed that some files have svn:eol=LF set.  What's the difference between eol and eol-style and will it cause issues if a file has both properties set.

Answer (score 5):

The section on [end-of-line handling in the red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.eol-style) makes no mention of `svn:eol`, so I'm fairly certain that it is not a property that SVN recognizes.  Whoever set it probably just got mixed up and meant to set `svn:eol-style`.